# Jquery load() loading more than I want

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load just the contents of a `<div>` into another `<div>` on the same page using a jquery function. But when the function triggers, it loads the entire `<HTML>` document into the specified `<div>`. Any idea why it would be doing this? My code is as follows:

Jquery:

```
function button1() {
    $('#sidebar-content').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load('#button1').fadeIn();
    });
}
function button2() {
    $('#sidebar-content').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load('#button2').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content-holder"> 
    <div id="main-content" class="float-holder"> 
        <div id="inner">
            <h1>BRAND TRUTH</h1>
            <div id="flashcontent">
                <div id="button1">
                    <div id="content">
                        <h1>Brand Truth</h1>
                        <p>What this basically means is our way of working, the process involved by both ourselves and our client.</p>

                        <p>When the truth wheel process is followed, the end result is so much stronger.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="button2">
                    <div id="content">
                        <h1>Button 2 Content</h1>
                        <p>Some other content</p>

                        <p>Some other content x2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // <![CDATA[

                var so = new SWFObject("working.swf", "working", "400", "400", "9", "#FFFFFF");
                so.write("flashcontent");

                // ]]>
            </script>

        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div id="sidebar-content">
                Replace Content Here!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end #main-content --> 
</div><!-- end #content-holder -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a function to load a remote webpage via AJAX, what you want is to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), like this:

```
function button1() {
    $('#sidebar-content').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html($('#button1').html()).fadeIn();
    });
}
function button2() {
    $('#sidebar-content').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).html($('#button2').html()).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

`.html()` without a parameter gets the html inside, so we're getting it from the button `<div>`, then `.html(string)` sets the html inside, which we're doing with the result.